# Firefox not running jQuery for XHTML output

Tags: jquery, firefox, xslt, xhtml

Okay, I did a crappy job of describing the issue in my previous post. I think the discussion got sidetracked from the core issue - so I'm going to try again.  *[Mea Culpa](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mea_culpa)* to **Elzo Valugi** about the aforementioned thread.

I have an XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="wtf.xsl"?>
<Paragraphs>
  <Paragraph>Hi</Paragraph>
</Paragraphs>
```

Simple enough.  I also have a stylesheet to create XHTML output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:output method="xml"
          indent="yes"
          doctype-system="http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"
          doctype-public="-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
          omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
      <head>
        <title>FF-JS-XHTML WTF</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="wtf.js"></script>
      </head>
      <body>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Paragraph">
    <p>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </p>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Last but not least, I have the following jQuery *[in toto](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_toto)* (wtf.js, from the script tag in the stylesheet):

```
$(function() {
    alert('Hiya!');
    $('<p>Hello</p>').appendTo('body');
});
```

Extremely simple, but sufficient for the demonstration.  When I run this in Internet Explorer, I get the alert 'Hiya!' as well as the expected:

```
Hi

Hello
```

but when I run it in Firefox (3.0.1), I still get the alert, but the jQuery does not insert the paragraph into the DOM, and I just get this:

```
Hi
```

If I change the stylesheet to **method="html"** it works fine, and I get (along with the alert):

```
Hi

Hello
```

Why doesn't Firefox run the jQuery with an XHTML document?  Has anyone any experience with this problem?

## EDIT: ADDITIONAL INFO

I can successfully insert elements into the documents this way in Firefox (method="xml"):

```
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
var p = document.createElement('p');
p.appendChild(document.createTextNode('Ipsum Lorem'));
frag.appendChild(p);
$('body').append(frag);
```

but I'm running into a similar problem with the **.remove()** method.

It is looking more and more that Firefox doesn't construct a DOM from XML that jQuery can relate to, or somesuch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with jQuery, but it looks to me like jQuery is using innerHTML to add the "Hello" fragment (jquery.1.3.2.js line 911) which won't work with XHTML.

Comment: @Alohci: Huzzah!  Progress!  Now... what jQuery statement would you use as an  alternative?  Is this even possible in jQuery?  Figures it would work in IE6.  Stupid crap browser...

Comment: Frankly, I don't know what the level of support jQuery has for XHTML. I suggest you ask on one of the jQuery mailing lists. As for IE, it works because IE doesn't support XHTML as XML, it just treats it as normal HTML where, of course, "innerHTML" works just fine.

Comment: I was premature marking this as answered.  Sorry.  The innerHTML bit doesn't explain why I can use the append() method successfully when I create the node in a document fragment (see EDIT).

Comment: Well, it looks like the purpose of the block of code starting at Line 871 and ending at 941 (i.e. including the innerHTML call) is to convert an HTML string to DOM nodes (at least that's what the comment says it does at line 871) so if you pass in a document fragment, then it's not going to have make the innerHTML call since the fragment is already a node.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
$.("body").text("<p>Hello</p>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it this issue? http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/4895
They suggest using `xsl:output method="html"` instead of `xsl:output method="xml"`.

Comment: Found a good list of what's required to make application/xml documents work in Firefox: http://ajaxandxml.blogspot.com/2009/03/firefox-xslt-errors.html

I solved my issue by fixing the <html> tag.